# Need to calculate cost based on Weight percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I needed to create a report based on the calculation of weight and cost. Other things I have done but how to calculate the cost is what is missing and I am not getting any idea how to achieve this.
Can someone please suggest how to achieve this output.

Here is the test data.

```
Create table #temp
(
    ID int,
    StopNumber int,
    [Weight] int,
    Cost decimal (18,2),
    Category nvarchar(max)
)

Insert into #temp values (1,1,5719,3099,'Linehaul')
Insert into #temp values (1,2,2627,393.82,'Fuel')
Insert into #temp values (1,3,3096,215,'Accessorial')
Insert into #temp values (2,1,6000,4500,'Linehaul')
Insert into #temp values (2,2,5000,383.82,'Fuel')
Insert into #temp values (2,3,4000,315,'Accessorial')

select * from #temp

ID  StopNumber  Weight  Cost    Category 
1       1       5719    3099.00 Linehaul 
1       2       2627    393.82  Fuel 
1       3       3096    215.00  Accessorial 
2       1       6000    4500.00 Linehaul 
2       2       5000    383.82  Fuel 
2       3       4000    315.00  Accessorial
```

Expected output

```
ID  StopNumber  Weight  Cost    Category    LineHaul    Fuel    Accessorial  
1      1        5719    3099.00 Linehaul    1,548.96    196.84  107.46 
1      2        2627    393.82  Fuel        711.51      90.42   49.36 
1      3        3096    215.00  Accessorial 838.53      106.56  58.18 
2      1        6000    4500.00 Linehaul    1,800.00    153.53  126 
2      2        5000    383.82  Fuel        1,500.00    128     105 
2      3        4000    315.00  Accessorial 1,200.00    102.35  84
```

Need to calculate the Linehaul,Fuel and Accessorial cost based on weight percentage.

For eg : Sum of weight of ID 1 = 11442
Sum of weight of ID 2 = 15000

Now 5719/11442 = 50%
2727/11442 = 23%
3096/11442 = 27%

Linehual Total Cost for ID 1    = 3099
Fuel Total Cost for ID 1        = 393.82
Accessorial Total Cost for ID 1 = 215

So Linehaul cost will be distributed among 3 weight based on the percentage calculation

3099 * 50 % = 1548.96
3099 * 23 % = 711.51
3099 * 27 % = 838.53

Same calculation will be done for Fuel and Accessorial cost as well and for different ID.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 or 2012? Please only tag the RDBMS version you are using.

Comment: You're probably looking for a window function to work out your totals in order to calculate a proportion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use window function with `sum()` aggregate.

For total weight by ID

```
sum([Weight]) over (partition by ID)`
```

Similarly you can use `CASE` expression with window function to find the cost for a category for a ID, example for Linehaul

```
sum(case when Category = 'Linehaul' then [Cost] end) over (partition by ID)
```

---

```
select  *,
        Linehaul    = [Weight] * 1.0 / sum([Weight]) over (partition by ID) 
                    * sum(case when Category = 'Linehaul' then [Cost] end) over (partition by ID),
        Fuel        = [Weight] * 1.0 / sum([Weight]) over (partition by ID) 
                    * sum(case when Category = 'Fuel' then [Cost] end) over (partition by ID),
        Accessorial = [Weight] * 1.0 / sum([Weight]) over (partition by ID) 
                    * sum(case when Category = 'Accessorial' then [Cost] end) over (partition by ID)
from    #temp t
order by ID, StopNumber
```

---

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c3da7ed2d18a8786d8ac8b4586b18609)

Comment: Fantastic this is what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function to calculate the totals for each id.  The rest is just arithmetic.  If I'm following your logic correctly:

```
select t.*,
       (weight / id_linehaul) * (cost) as linehaul,
       (weight / id_fuel) * (cost) as fuel,
       (weight / id_accessorial) * (cost) as accessorial
from (select t.*,
             sum(weight) over (partition by id) as id_weight,
             sum(case when category = 'Linehaul' then cost end) over (partition by id) as id_linehaul,
             sum(case when category = 'Fuel' then cost end) over (partition by id) as id_fuel,
             sum(case when category = 'Accessorial' then cost end) over (partition by id) as id_accessorial
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, But the output is not correct Gordon. Linehaul , Fuel and Accessorial cost are not calculating as expected